# Strange set of characters (including question box) instead of Hyper modifier key

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, x11, xorg

As many people before me, I have set Caps Lock to Hyper_L using a variety of methods (xmodmap, setxkbmap, the system settings). However, in all of these methods an issue arises, I get a strange looking set of characters that looks vaguely like {•.∆ in place of the hyper key (delta being more of a question mark inside of a rotated square). When I hit hyper_l in a textbox nothing happens

I managed to get my capslock thing to work on GNOME fedora but, I really like the idea of KDE and want to use it there.

Xev registers always that I am hitting the Hyper_L key, but my computer either treats it as Super or nothing (nothing being that strange character).

It really feels like system settings just cannot use Hyper as a modifier key, or even recognize it.

It may feel like a small detail, but being able to use capslock as hyper is a crucial part of migrating from windows to Linux for me. I cherish any and all time you have dedicated to reading, considering and helping me out.

***Below are some details to be more specific with my problem.

Possibly relevant "specs": X11 session, Fedora 38 KDE spin

Hypothesis: I feel like the only difference between my setup on GNOME and KDE was I had ticked "Use emacs inputs" with GNOME tweaks. Not saying that's it, but it's the one thing I can think of that is different (besides actual DE chosen).

I have tried:
•Setxkbmap caps:hyper
•xmodmap (clearing mod3, clearing lock, removing hyper from mod4 and adding it to mod3)
•The system settings "change capslock behavior"
•Changing my keyboard layout